# SVN exception E210004: Malformed network data in Jenkins

Tags: svn, jenkins

When checking out slightly bigger files from SVN such as .jar files (from Jenkins) I often get a strange SVN malformed network data exception.

```
org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E210004: Malformed network data
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:64)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:51)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.svn.SVNReader.readItem(SVNReader.java:422)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.svn.SVNReader.readItem(SVNReader.java:456)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.svn.SVNReader.readItem(SVNReader.java:456)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.svn.SVNReader.readTuple(SVNReader.java:288)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.svn.SVNConnection.readTuple(SVNConnection.java:280)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.svn.SVNEditModeReader.readTuple(SVNEditModeReader.java:265)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.svn.SVNEditModeReader.driveEditor(SVNEditModeReader.java:221)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.svn.SVNRepositoryImpl.update(SVNRepositoryImpl.java:1503)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc16.SVNUpdateClient16.update(SVNUpdateClient16.java:557)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc16.SVNUpdateClient16.doCheckout(SVNUpdateClient16.java:965)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.old.SvnOldCheckout.run(SvnOldCheckout.java:19)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.old.SvnOldCheckout.run(SvnOldCheckout.java:8)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnOperationRunner.run(SvnOperationRunner.java:20)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperationFactory.run(SvnOperationFactory.java:1221)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperation.run(SvnOperation.java:292)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNUpdateClient.doCheckout(SVNUpdateClient.java:781)
```

Does anyone have an idea about this? Network traffic travels through a VPN. Even though there would be some slight "hickup" in the connection, I would assume the checkout process would be able to recover from this.

Comment: i am having the same issue, also through VPN

Comment: I second that. Happens when checking out over Cisco Anyconnect VPN client. Haven't found a fix though.